# 'AWSHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'ssl_context'

Tags: aws-cli

```
Not working
    root@49161b16e779:/# aws --version
    aws-cli/1.11.121 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.10.0-32-generic botocore/1.5.84
    root@49161b16e779:/# aws s3 ls s3://my.bucket.path
    'AWSHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'ssl_context'

Working fine
    tada@tada-VirtualBox:~$ aws --version
    aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.10.0-32-generic botocore/1.4.70
```

The above is a problem I'm getting lately, since somewhere between July 25 and Aug 3, 2017.

Docker is node:6.9.2. Also tried the 'ubuntu' image, same error.

I can't seem to find the error source. Anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

This is caused by a bug in AWS CLI, noted at https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1258#issuecomment-321787841, that mades it incompatible with *newer* versions of *Requests*. If you install `awscli` with Pip, you won't see the bug, because the version that you get from Pip has an old, compatible version of *Requests* baked into it. But if you've installed AWS CLI with Apt (or perhaps some other package managers), you'll have got a version of AWS CLI that uses the system's *Requests* module, exposing you to this bug.

To fix, either:

1. Remove whatever version of the AWS CLI you've got installed and reinstall it with Pip. This probably means running `apt remove awscli && pip install awscli`.

... OR, if you can't do that for some reason:

2. *Downgrade* Requests to version 2.12, which according to https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1258#issuecomment-331746809 is compatible with the old versions of AWS CLI, by running `pip uninstall requests && pip install requests==2.12` or `pip3 uninstall requests && pip3 install requests==2.12`.

I believe this issue is [fixed as of botocore v1.11.0](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1466#issuecomment-415928969), so eventually, once the version of awscli in Apt's repositories uses a botocore version >= v1.11.0, this bug should go away.

Comment: Problem hasn't gone away yet.